# C++ calling super class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am mostly a Java and AS3 programmer but right now I am working in C++ for something and I stumbled upon a problem.
I have a base class (let's call it ClassA) that has a private variable var1. In this class I have a method getVar1() that returns a pointer to that variable.

Next I have another class that extends Base (let's call it ClassB). How do I call the getVar1() from the super class?
In java it is as simple as this.var1 = super.getVar1().

I read that it is like var1 = ClassA::getVar1(), but I am not sure if this is OK for work with variables (aka the pointers can change).

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `super` because of multiple inheritance.

Comment: Hmmmm private variable with a get accessor that returns a pointer - nice...

Comment: @Ricibob I know it is not nice but it is not my code. I am working on something written my other a long time ago. Sadly there is no time refactor everything.

Comment: Sure understood - not offence intended - just couldn't help myself ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's ok to call it ClassA::getVar1().

However, if you want the java-way, you can make the method "virtual". This means whenever you write getVar1(), it doesn't depend on the Type you wrote in front of it (so at compile time) but it depends on the type of the object when you call it (at runtime). For this reason, c++ keeps an internal v-table to find the appropriate method. It's equivalent to the java way and called late-binding.

Answer (score 3):

`getVar1()` should be enough

```
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
...
   void foo() { yourvartype* v = getVar1(); ... }
};
```

if you OTOH have defined another `getVar1()` in `ClassB` then `ClassA::getVar1()` should be used to help the compiler to identify which function to call.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example showing what happens:
- A initializes x at 10
- B initializes x at 20
below you can see how virtual function calls work out and how calling your parent works out (even if you initialized the value differently)

**the biggest thing to keep in mind is that even if you call your super function (A::GetX), it still uses the value from your own class (B::x)**

```
class A
{
public:
    A::A() : x(10) {}
virtual int GetX() {return x*2;}
protected:
    int x; 
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B::B() : A()
    {
        x = 20;
    }
    virtual int GetX() {return x;}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A* a1 = new A();
    B* b1 = new B();
    int test1 = a1->GetX(); // returns 20 (because x is 10, but function doubles value)
    int test2 = b1->GetX(); // returns 20 (because x is initialized at 20)
    return 0;
}
```

now if we change the B::GetX to:

```
virtual int GetX() {return A::GetX();}
```

We get the following result:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
A* a1 = new A();
B* b1 = new B();
int test1 = a1->GetX(); //returns 20 (as previously)
int test2 = b1->GetX(); // return 40 (x is initialized by B at 20, but then the
                        // A:GetX is called, which doubles the result)
return 0;
}
```